# Collective term for interpolation and extrapolation

Tags: terminology, interpolation, extrapolation

Is there a collective term for both interpolation and extrapolation? If there is such a term, what is it?

Comment: Possibly stats.stackexchange.com might give you a better answer to this than this forum would.

Comment: Imputation is a general word for when you "fill in the blanks" such as "multiple imputation" a la Rubin

Comment: approximation, (surface) reconstruction, model fitting

Answer (score 0):

Control theorists sometimes use the word "filtering" to describe both.

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146171/hypernym-for-interpolation-and-extrapolation

has several suggestions, including "regression", "fitting", and "estimation".